# concatenate values in less (css) without a space

Tags: css, less

So I'm trying to make a LESS mixin which takes a number (degrees to rotate) and output the correct css to rotate the element. The problem is, I can't figure out a way to write both "270deg" and "3" (270/90) for IE. Here are the things i've tried:

```
.rotate(@rotation: 0) {
    @deg: deg;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(@rotation deg); // i can see why this doesn't work
    -moz-transform: rotate((@rotation)deg); // parens
    -o-transform: rotate(@rotation+deg); // variable-keyword concatenation
    transform: rotate(@rotation+@deg); // variable-variable concatenation

    // this is the reason I need @rotation to be just a number:
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=@rotation/90);
}

.someElement {
    .rotate(270)
}
```

For now i've just modified the compiler script so that it doesn't put a space between variable/keyword concatenation. I'd hope theres a better solution.

Comment: Why not call it like: `.rotate(270deg)` ? Is it because of the IE thing?

Comment: Yeah its cause of the IE thing

Comment: Out of interest whats the real advantage of LESS, doesn't really seem to make that much difference in code length. Some of the functions seem redundant as most styles I work on aren't dynamic. 

I can see that changing a colour value in one place would be nice, but find and replace does that occasional editing job without adding any (seemingly unnecessary) JavaScript load.

Comment: If you use CSS for anything but the most basic of styling, you'll quickly find that it takes almost 0 advantage of code/style symmetry, and forces you to build difficult-to-maintain styles - especially if you have styles that depend on eachother (lets say you want the color of one element to be slightly darker than another element, or you need related font sizes, positioning, etc). If parameterized mixins like the .rotate one I wrote above don't pique your interest, maybe the stuff you're working on is just so simple you don't need to worry about maintainability.

Comment: Oh, also I'm using less.php - so theres no javascript load at all. The less is translated to css, cached, and sent the browser on demand as normal css. Also, with less.php @imports in less all translate into a single css file - so you don't get import chaining with your browser needing to request each chained import individually. This reduces both load and latency.

Comment: instead of concatenation, use math: `-webkit-transform(@rotation * 1deg)`. On my own project, I spent about 30 minutes trying to figure out how to concatenate `@num` with `%` and it just hit me. just multiply `@num * 1%`!!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

One solution, although a little ugly, would be to used escaped strings:

```
@degs: ~"@{rotation}deg"
@degs-ie: @rotation / 90;
transform: rotate(@degs);
filter: ~"DXImageBlahBlah(rotation=@{degs-ie})"
```

Note you need less.js v1.1.x for this.

Comment: Oh but less.php doesn't support escaped values, so I'll stick with my solution for now. I guess.. side question: why does concatenation like @degrees+deg put a space between them? I'd think it would be better to say that @x: X;@x+something will output Xsomething, and then @x+ something would output X something. Then you don't have this strange limitation

Comment: `x + y` is actually undefined by the language, when x & y aren't both variables containing numbers, or literal numbers. `deg` on its own is treated as a symbol, such as `normal`, `bold` etc, and those always stand on their own. So in this case, `a + deg` is the same thing as `a deg`. The `+` is simply ignored by the language.

Answer (score 26):

A cleaner approach is to use `unit` ([official documentation](http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-unit)):

```
unit(@rotation, deg)
```

which in your example becomes:

```
transform: rotate(unit(@transition, deg));
```

**Documentation:**

unit(dimension, *unit*)

- dimension: A number, with or without a dimension
- unit (optional): the unit to change to, or if omitted it will remove the unit

Answer (score 3):

Thank you cloudhead. 
Since the escaping for LESS PHP is a little different, this is what worked for me:

```
.rotation(@rotation:90){
  @degs: e("@{rotation}deg");
  @degs-ie: @rotation / 90;

  -webkit-transform: rotate(@degs);
  -moz-transform: rotate(@degs);
  transform: rotate(@degs);
  filter: e("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=@{degs-ie})");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that found this old item about concatenation without spaces, there is a bug/feature request in LESS #1375 (Opened in 2013, unfixed as of Jan 2016) that describes the problem.

Problem:

```
@CharTinySpace: \\2009;
content: "@CharTinySpace@CharTinySpace";
```

Output:

```
content: " \2009 \2009 ";
```

Which adds extra space to the display.

<del>A solution can be to use an embedded JavaScript replacement:</del>

```
@CharTinySpace: \\2009;
content: `"@{CharTinySpace}@{CharTinySpace}".replace(/ /g,"")`;
```

Output:

```
content: "\2009\2009";
```

Not the best solution, but the only one that worked in my instance where I want readable varables instead of unicode escape values.

---

Update: Thanks to seven-phases-max, the proper solution is MUCH simpler.

```
@CharTinySpace: \\2009;
content: "@{CharTinySpace}@{CharTinySpace}";
```

I'm leaving this here in case the JavaScript option is a useful clue to future discoverers.