# LESS string interpolation

Tags: css, less

I'm specifying font sizes in Ems, which means they're relative to the parent container.  I have several child elements and don't want to repeat the parent size each time when I do calculations on it. So I have:

```
@articleFontSize: 21/16;
```

If, further on, I use:

```
font-size: @articleFontSizeem;
```

as you'd expect, I get 'variable @articleFontSizeem is undefined'.

If I interpolate it:

```
font-size: @{articleFontSize}em;
```

then again it refuses to compile and I just get a plain 'syntax error'.

```
font-size: @articleFontSize~"em";
```

This compiles - but in the output I get code like:

```
font-size: 1.3125 em;
```

i.e. it's added a space before the units, so they're ignored by the browser.

I'm running LiveReload on a Mac (2.0 beta 5) which according to the settings uses 'System Ruby 1.8.7' for the compilation.

**UPDATED SOLUTIONS:**

a. Add a zero amount of the correct units:

```
font-size: 0em + @articleFontSize;
```

b. (my earlier alternative method - using a function):

```
.rFont(@target, @context) {
    @ratio: @target/@context;
    font-size: ~"@{ratio}em";
}
```

Called with:

```
.rFont(11,@articleFontSize);
```

Output (correct, note no unwanted spaces):

```
font-size: 0.7063571428571428em;
```

I didn't expect putting @{ratio} inside tilde+quotes to still expand it.  But it works (almost nothing else does.)

This question helped:
[concatenate values in less (css) without a space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027232/concatenate-values-in-less-css-without-a-space)

Comment: The escape method has helped me, thank you

Comment: This is kind of mixed with another question: "How to convert a LESS variable to another unit?" #justSaying — So, the actual basic answer to "How to do string interpolation in LESS?" is: `"@{my-var}"`. Only this one shows up in a rule such as `.hidden&::before { content: "@{my-var}"; display: block; }`. Got it, thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
font-size: 0em + @articleFontSize;
```

Comment: beautiful hack but you no longer need it considering you can write `font-size: unit(@articleFontSize, em);`

Answer (score 1):

Can you put the em in the articleFontSize variable? For example:

```
@articleFontSize: 21/16em;
```

Or if that doesn't work maybe:

```
@articleFontSize: (21/16)em;
```

Comment: Yes, you can.  I'd previously ruled that out, but it looks like my logic was wrong - I should really be setting:

Comment: (2nd attempt) I'd actually need to set the initial size to '21' (no formula or units) so I can later do: font-size: 12/@articleFontSize and express it it Ems. (If I'd written it without LESS, I'd have to change 12/16em to 12/21em to get the right size, if you see what I mean..) Maybe I'm better off putting it in by hand...

Comment: @articleFontSize: (21/@articleFontSize)em;  Brackets don't work either - it validates, but again there's an extraneous space *regardless* of whether you use variable name of just 21/16 etc.  I don't get where the space is coming from…

Comment: Could you do like `@tempSize: 21em`, `@articleFontSize: @tempSize / 16`

Comment: You can specify units with the number and they're added correctly (on either side of the equation) but not after the variable name.  I don't especially like that solution because variable declarations like "21em" are (to me anyway) very confusing as that's a huge size which doesn't reflect the actual value.  I decided to write a function & then found it's possible to wrap the entire thing in quotes & it's still parsed - solution above.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: be careful with REM. - as well as IE 8 and below opera mini still doesn't support it. Plus some older versions of webkit won't parse rem if use in a media query.

Answer (score -3):

Have a look at [the `rem` measurement unit](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem) instead. It has all the benefits of relative ems/%, yet maintains the predictability of px and prevents 'compound sizing' child elems.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question. The type of unit is irrelevant