# Concatenate string and var less css

Tags: css, less

Can anyone please tell me how to concatenate a var and a string in LESS so I don't have the space between them?

I have the following code:

```
.text(@size) {
    font-size: @size + px;
    line-height: (@size / 10) + em;
}

h1 {
   .text(16)
}
```

What the LESS outputs is the following:

```
h1 {
    font-size: 12 px;
    line-height: 1.2 em;
}
```

I need to find a way to remove the spaces.

Thanks
Pete

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027232/concatenate-values-in-less-css-without-a-space

Answer (score 47):

In case any late-comers find this thread:

There is a built-in function for this:

```
unit(@dimension, [@unit: ""]);
```

So `font-size: unit(@size, px);` should result in `font-size: 12px`. I tested it.

http://lesscss.org/#reference

Comment: if you want to use percent as unit, I had to do `unit(@size, ~"%");`

Comment: This is by far, the most valid and working solution. I was able to fix the exact same issue using the above solution. It's a shame that this answer was not accepted as the solution.

Answer (score 6):

U can use something like this:

```
.text(@size) {
    @lineheight: @size / 10;
    font-size: ~"@{size}px";
    line-height: ~"@{lineheight}em";
}
```

But on lesscss.org is this: prior to less 1.3.1 a (~"@{name}") type of selector was supported. **Support for this will be removed in the near future**.

I think another way of solution is not possible.

Comment: Interpolation for selectors will be removed, but not inline like in your example.

Answer (score 4):

I think the cleanest way (without string interpolation) is to add 0px to your variable, e.g. `@size + 0px`.

Answer (score 3):

In a case you need to use it in combination with CSS function (eg. calc), here is one way:

```
@width: 12;
width: %(~"calc(33%% - %dpx)", @width);
```

Outputs:

```
width: calc(33% - 12px);
```

Answer (score 2):

this is how I recently solved a similar problem.

```
.text(@size: 10) {
  font-size: e(%("%dpx", @size));
  line-height: e(%("%dem", @size/10));
}
```

The %("string", value) function simply format a string and so it take the %d inside the string and transform it in whatever is value.
an example here: http://cdpn.io/hAbwl

Hope this can help.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to solve my string concatenation problem with this.  IE requires quotes around the color string unlike other color rules in it's gradient filter.

Answer (score -1):

Less replaces anything but values with spaces, so to convert units you add 0 of that unit. Just dont pass in a unit value.

```
.my_mixin(@num) {
 @result: @num / 16; //12 / 16
 font-size: @result + 0em; //0.750em
}

p {
 .my_mixin(12);
}
```

Hope this helps someone else.