# Add units to a less variable

Tags: css, less

If I have a numerical LESS variable for line-height

```
@lineHeight: 1.2
```

how do I add em to the end of it to set the height of the element to produce:

```
height: 1.2em;
```

The following do not work:

```
height: @(lineHeight)em;
height: @(lineHeight)"em";
height: @(lineHeight) + "em";
height: @lineHeight + "em";
```

I have seen other threads where the answer is adding a unit is not easy, but that doesn't seem right as the numerical line-height value goes hand in hand with the em unit.

Comment: Use either [`unit`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-unit) function: `unit(@lineHeight, em)` or arithmetic unit propagation: `@lineHeight * 1em`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenate string and var less css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724227/concatenate-string-and-var-less-css)

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution in a [shopware theme-mixin](https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/5.4/themes/Frontend/Bare/frontend/_public/src/less/_mixins/unitize.less#L33)

```
 height: ~"@{lineHeight}px";
```

But the solution from `seven-phases-max` in your comments works too

```
 height: unit(@lineHeight, px);
```