# Less adds unexpected space to variable

Tags: variables, less

For some reason, the output of nth child is rendered with un unexpected space. Can anyone help?

Renders:

```
// Part of render
body.domain-bsci-fta-local #block-domain-switcher ul li:nth-child( 3) {
  background-color: #e14313;
}
```

From code:

```
// Variables
@a-primary: #018f9e;
@b-primary: #2b6a7c;
@c-primary: #e14313;
@d-primary: #009966;

@domain-a: 'a-local';
@domain-b: 'b-fta-local';
@domain-c: 'c-fta-local';
@domain-d: 'd-fta-local';

@domains: @domain-a @a-primary 1, @domain-b @b-primary 2, @domain-c @c-primary 3, @domain-d @d-primary 4;

// Call
body {
  .generate-menus();
}

// Functions
.generate-menus() {
  .for(@domains);
  .-each(@domain) {
    @dn: e(extract(@domain, 1));
    @dc: extract(@domain, 2);
    @dr: extract(@domain,3);
    .generate-menu(@dn, @dc, @dr);
  }
}
.generate-menu(@domainname, @domaincolor, @domaincount) {
  &.domain-@{domainname} {
    #block-domain-switcher {
      ul {
        li {
          &:nth-child(@{domaincount}) {
            background-color: @domaincolor;
            a {
              border-bottom: 5px solid;
              color: white !important;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    .navigation .submenu {
      background-color: @domaincolor;
    }
  }
}

// ............................................................
// .for

.for(@i, @n) {
  .-each(@i)
}

.for(@n) when (isnumber(@n)) {
  .for(1, @n)
}

.for(@i, @n) when not (@i = @n) {
  .for((@i + (@n - @i) / abs(@n - @i)), @n);
}

// ............................................................
// .for-each

.for(@array) when (default()) {
  .for-impl_(length(@array))
}

.for-impl_(@i) when (@i > 1) {
  .for-impl_((@i - 1))
}

.for-impl_(@i) when (@i > 0) {
  .-each(extract(@array, @i))
}
```

Comment: It's not a real solution, that's why I post it as a comment and not as a real answer. You could use LESS PHP (http://leafo.net/lessphp/) and do the following (with PHP): Open the file, use a regex to find an nth-child selector with an unnecessary white-space and then remove it.

Comment: Yes, I could do that, but it is not needed as I can do it in many tools. But I do want to solve this issue

Comment: Just update your compiler. This was fixed in v2.x.

Comment: @seven-phases-max: I did not check this in 2.x but OP said (in comments to the answer) that they were already using 2.0.

Comment: @Harry Well, it's barely possible since it's [#2182](https://github.com/less/less.js/pull/2182) merged into early v2 betas (so would rather triple check the version).

Comment: @seven-phases-max: You were the one who fixed it. I should have known better :D. By the way, I did check in 2.1.1 and can confirm that it does work. Modified my answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note:** As mentioned by seven-phases-max in [his comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919330/less-adds-unexpected-space-to-variable/27922730#comment44258438_27919330) to the question, this was a bug which has already been **fixed in v2.x**. Leaving this answer (with the work-around solution) as-is to help future readers who can't upgrade their compiler for whatever reason.

The problem happens only for selectors which use selector interpolation and are nested within one or more parent selectors. It can be solved by using a temporary variable which contains the pseudo-selector like below: (it uses escaped string feature)

**Option 1:**

```
ul {
    li {
        @selector: ~":nth-child(@{domaincount})"; /* the selector is formed here */
        &@{selector} { /* and used here */
            background-color: @domaincolor;
            a {
                border-bottom: 5px solid;
                color: white !important;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
li { 
    @count: ~"(@{domaincount})";
    &:nth-child@{count} { /* and used here */
        background-color: @domaincolor;
        a {
            border-bottom: 5px solid;
            color: white !important;
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample Compiled Output:**

```
body.domain-a-local #block-domain-switcher ul li:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #018f9e;
}
```

**Related Links:**

- [concatenate values in less (css) without a space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027232/concatenate-values-in-less-css-without-a-space)
- [Redudant space in interpolated selectors like nth(...)](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1973)

---

As mentioned above and in the linked issue thread, the issue happens only when the selector is formed using selector interpolation and is nested under one or more parents.

**This works**

```
// Variables
@list: a 1;

@num: extract(@list, 2);
// Usage
body div:nth-child(@{num}) {
  color: #444;
}
```

**But this doesnt**

```
// Variables
@list: a 1;

@num: extract(@list, 2);
// Usage
body {
    div:nth-child(@{num}) {
        color: #444;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for this. I guess this is a bug in the less compiler then.

Comment: Hmmm option 2 gives me ParseError: Unrecognised input

Comment: What is the compiler version? I was using 1.7.5. Here is a [sample](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwpyGb) for Option 2 on CodePen.

Comment: @Nealv: The code in the CodePen demo that I posted in previous comment (for Option 2) works for me in the most latest compiler version 2.1.1 also. So I think there must be something else causing  the problem for you.

Comment: @Nealv: I have updated the answer based on seven-phases-max' comment that it was indeed a bug which was fixed.

Comment: I think this is a very elaborate and full answer. Thanks alot, I think this will help many people.

Comment: @Nealv: Welcome mate. A big part of the credit goes to seven-phases-max too for pointing to the GitHub issue log and its fix.